# android code for app ERROR

Tags: java, android

the final line and the 4th line "EditText numTxt;" contain errors but i cannot seem to work them out, it says about missing a } but it isnt resolved when i enter these or other things similar. 
not sure what the problem is here but i was following a tutorial and this is exactly how the code looked

```
 public class SecondScreen extends Activity {
Button sendSMS;
EditText msgTxt;
EditText numTxt;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondscreen);

    TextView SecondScreenText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SecondScreenText);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Receiving the Data
    String value = i.getStringExtra("value");


    // Displaying Received data
    SecondScreenText.setText(value);

    sendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendsms);
    msgTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
    numTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
    sendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String myMsg = msgTxt.getText().toString();
            String theNumber = numTxt.getText().toString();
            sendMsg(theNumber, myMsg);



    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }


    });
        }


protected void sendMsg(String theNumber, String myMsg) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(theNumber, null, myMsg, null, null);
}
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you've lost a `}` somewhere in the `new View.OnClickListener()`.

Comment: You've basically added the declaration and onclicklistener of the next button within the onclicklistener of the sendSms button.

Answer (score 0):

just end your code with this statement completion , which mean :

```
protected void sendMsg(String theNumber, String myMsg) {
   SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
   sms.sendTextMessage(theNumber, null, myMsg, null, null);}
                  });}}
```

hope help you.

Comment: @user2307582 did you check my answer